# How to make LaTex table vertical row headers fit?

Tags: latex, tabular, overleaf

For reference, this is what I am trying to achieve:

[image: Desired outcome]

This is what my current table looks like:

[image: Current table]

This is the problem I am trying to solve (making the class names longer breaks the table):

[image: Cursed table]

Here are the the required packages to reproduce the table:

```
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
```

And here is the code for the table that we generated with my butler ChatGPT:

```
\begin{table*}[ht]
  \centering
  \footnotesize
  \begin{tabular}{lp{4cm}ccp{5cm}}
    \toprule
    \multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Test TYPE and description}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Failure Rate (\%)}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Example test cases \& \colorbox{gray}{expected behavior}}} \\
    & & \textbf{BERT} & \textbf{BiLSTM} & \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Predicate Identification}} & Test 1 description & 10 & 30 & Expected behavior for Test 1 \\
    & Test 2 description & 15 & 35 & Expected behavior for Test 2 \\
    & Test 3 description & 20 & 40 & Expected behavior for Test 3 \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Class B}} & Test 4 description & 5 & 15 & Expected behavior for Test 4 \\
    & Test 5 description & 10 & 20 & Expected behavior for Test 5 \\
    & Test 6 description & 15 & 25 & Expected behavior for Test 6 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Example of a table with rotated row headings, separated rows, one value per group, and a description of the test for each row.}
  \label{tab:example}
\end{table*}
```

I tried adding '\\' to the vertical row headers, but it did not work (still stayed as one long line)

Is there a way to ensure that the table resizes dynamically? And how about keeping some of the Classes with fewer tests horizontal to save space?

Comment: Can you please make a [mre], a small, but compilable test document?

Comment: Better suited for https://tex.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

Regarding rotated content, there simply hasn't been allocated enough space for the longer text, which causing everything to break. On top of that, `\rotatebox` creates a simple one-line box without line breaks. A remedy to your issues is (1) a paragraph box s.a. `\parbox` which automatically add linebreaks  and (2) anything that intriduce extra spaces.

For the latter case (2), one can add extra empty rows before and after a group and increase a number of merged rows in `\multirow`. Another way is to add struts in the first and in the last row of the group. However, long texts would still cause a problem. This can be mitigated by using a trick with a zero-length box (e.g. `\makebox[0pt]...`)--**see the code**. As to the struts, I find `\xmathstrut` of  `mathtools` a very convenient way to create extra spaces in tables. You could use bigstruts from `multirow` or play with gapes from `makecell` or use invisible rules etc.

Depending on how long is the rotated text, you might consider stretching the whole table by increasing a factor of `arraystretch`, such as

```
\renewcommand\arraytretch{1.5}   % X = 1.0 is the default value
```

in order to balance spacing in other rows, as well.

I'd suggest to define a custom colour instead of using absolute values to avoid repetition every time you want to highlight something. I also found that `\colorbox` slightly increases height in a header, which can be cancelled by `\smash{}`. Remove it if you find text too tight.

```latex
\documentclass[margin=2.5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}   % for \xmathstrut
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{makecell}    % for \thead

\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{\Gape[0pt][0pt]}
\colorlet{highlight}{gray!30}

\NewCommandCopy\oldxmathstrut\xmathstrut
\RenewDocumentCommand\xmathstrut{O{#2}m}{%
    \ensuremath{\oldxmathstrut[#1]{#2}}}


\begin{document}
  \footnotesize
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.15}
  \begin{tabular}{lp{4.5cm}ccp{4cm}}
    \toprule
    & \thead{Test TYPE and description}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Failure Rate (\%)}}
    & \thead{Example test cases \&} \\
    & & \thead{BERT} & \thead{BiLSTM} & \thead{\smash{\colorbox{highlight}{expected behavior}}}%
    \xmathstrut[0.5]{0} \\
    \midrule
    \multirow[c]{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\clap{%
        \parbox{1.5cm}{\centering Predicate\\Identification}}}}%
    \xmathstrut[0]{0.5}
    & Test 1 description & 10 & 30 & Expected behavior for Test 1 \\
    & Test 2 description & 15 & 35 & Expected behavior for Test 2 \\
    & Test 3 description & 20 & 40 & Expected behavior for Test 3 \xmathstrut[0.5]{0 }\\
    \midrule
    \multirow{3}{*}{%
        \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Class B}} & Test 4 description & 5 & 15 & Expected behavior for Test 4 \\
    & Test 5 description & 10 & 20 & Expected behavior for Test 5 \\
    & Test 6 description & 15 & 25 & Expected behavior for Test 6 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  % \caption{Example of a table with rotated row headings, separated rows, one value per group, and a description of the test for each row.}
\end{document}
```

[image]